# How can I delete text between two characters for Notepad ++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

Alright, so I have a line like this

```
 This is an example for TEXT HERE (IP HERE)
```

I need the text in between the space after for and before the ( to be gone.

So in this case, I would need the `TEXT HERE` Gone

This would make it read This is an example for IP
I've read a lot about regular expressions, but cant figure this out. Thanks!

Examples:

```
Nmap scan report for ns525464.ip-8-26-94.net (8.26.94.30)
Nmap scan report for ns525465.ip-8-26-94.net (8.26.94.31)
```

I need it to be

```
Nmap scan report for 8.26.94.30
Nmap scan report for 8.26.94.31
```

Comment: Please give some real example text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these expressions:

- find what: `for [^(]+\(([^)]+)\)`
- replace with: `for \1`
  (you can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/RhdWA5/1)

Don't forget to set search mode to "regular expression" in notepad++.